# Conditionally show hide asp linkbutton

Tags: asp.net, dynamic

I have below link button and I need to show it only if grid has records.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton1" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete file" Visible='<%# (Convert.ToInt32(Eval("gridViewFileInformation.Rows.Count"))>0) %>' >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

But it shows always.

Comment: what is the output HTML generated by this? is "true" or "false" written there?

Comment: doesn't show visible state after HTML code is generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code behind file after databind of "gridViewFileInformation" you can set the Visible property of linkButton1. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189799/asp-net-c-sharp-trying-to-hide-a-link-button/)

Something like:

ASPX File:

```
<asp:GridView
    runat="server"
    ID="gridViewFileInformation"
    OnDataBound="gridViewFileInformation_DataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

CS File:

```
protected void gridViewFileInformation_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    linkButton1.Visible = (gridViewFileInformation.Rows.Count > 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can do it in DataBound event but why doesn't my current code work?

Comment: I think this will answer your question [Set Visible property with server tag <%= %> in Framework 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595851/set-visible-property-with-server-tag-in-framework-3-5)